# suggestion on how to store (large) geolocalizated points in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I want to store several kind of Points of Interest in MongoDB.
a POI for me is something like

```
poi = 
{
 properties :
   {
    name: 'title',
    type: 'feature'      // GEOJson
    geometry : 
        { type: 'Point',
          coordinates : [lng, lat]
        },
    categories : ['red', 'green']
   },
  details :
    {
     photo: 'http://...',
     description : 'bla bla bla.....'
     etc...
    }
}
```

Since I'll use GeoNear, I separated the `poi` in 2 different collections: *properties* and *details*. So firstly, I'll research and show near pois on the *poi_properties* collection. Then once chosen one poi, I'll query its details on *poi_details* collection.
In the first research, besides coordinates, I filter results also by *categories*.  So the query will look like

```
 db.collection.poi_properties.find({$near: [lng, lat], categories:['red']});
```

So I have indexed *coordinates* and *categories*.

However, query is not so fast...  I guess because the collection is quite large (if I export it, it's about 200MB). Is there any useful technique/bast practice on how to store this kind of data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a geospatial index on coordinates?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

The syntax is as follows:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere" } )
```

Then you can retrieve your information quickly and return your results with one query.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought that you didn't have the geospatial index. So when you run the query with explain, does it show efficient index utilization?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain